# Как замокать метод с обращением в БД

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, codeception

Есть класс с двумя методами, один оперирует данными взятыми из второго. Нужно протестировать метод sum не получая данных из метода db, а подставив свои.

```
public function sum()
{
    $db = $this->db();
    return $db['a'] + $db['b'];
}

private function db()
{
    return ['a' => 1, 'b' => 3];
}
```

Пробовал замокать метод db и протестировать вот так

```
$this->class = $this->make(ClassName, [
    'db' => function() {
        return ['a' => 4, 'b' => 2]
    }
]);
$this->assertSame(6, $this->class->sum());
```

но при тесте мои данные не подставляются, по прежнему db вызванный в методе sum  возвращает старый массив  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так я делал, чтобы замокать метод.

```
    $class = new class () extends ClassName
    {
        private function db()
        {
            return ['a' => 4, 'b' => 2];
        }
    };
    $this->assertSame(6, $class->sum());
```